# How can I fetch all the associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Current_user has many favorite communities. Favorite communities can be fetched by this.

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)
```

Then each community has many topics just like this.

**Community has_many: Community_topics**
 **Community_topic belongs_to: Community**

Now, how can I fetch all the topics that are belonging to current_user's favorite communities?

I tried this

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)

@community_topics = Community_topics.where(:community_id => @communities).page(params[:page]).order("last_active_at DESC")
```

But I got this error:(

```
NameError (uninitialized constant UsersController::Community_topics):
```

Comment: it's typo issue? Try this `CommunityTopic.where("community_id in (?)"=> @communities.collect(&:id))`

Comment: @Amar Thanks. Now I've got this error:( `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column community_topics.community_id in (?) in where clause`

Comment: @Amar Could you please show me the correct code?

Comment: `Community has_many: community_topics
Community_topic belongs_to: community` and community topic should have community_id because it's has many relation

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to the letter:

> A has_many association indicates a one-to-many connection with another
>   model. You’ll often find this association on the “other side” of a
>   belongs_to association. This association indicates that each instance
>   of the model has zero or more instances of another model.

Make sure your spelling is correct, that you have a `parent_table_id` field in the child table, and you have declared that the child table `belongs_to` its parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a model:

```
e.g. my_model.rb
```

it contents should looke like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

so in controller you will call it:

```
@myvariable = MyModel.where(......)
```

Make sure of your naming conventions. Check if they are correct.